# Update the geofence as user move in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geolocation, proximity

I've created a Geofence based on the user's current location and wants to update it as users is moving for 10 meters in any direction.

Is it possible to remove and create the geofence so frequently? Specially in case of when the application is running in the background?

Comment: Yes, you can, but if you are tracking the user's location with GPS (which you would need to do in order to update the geofence region) what is the point of the geofence? It will never fire since the user will never leave the region.